# HTML5 multi-link

Tags: html, css

I am taking an intro class to website design and I am stuck on a particular problem. I am to create a multi-link at the bottom of the page which I did, however, I do not know how to make it so that a page does not link back to itself. We are supposed to make it look like this: [image]

This is the code that I came up with:
[image]

When I make one of the links a "#", it is still a link. So how do I make it italicized and not a link within the nav block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav>
<a href="HW2Part1.html">Tour Home</a> |
<span style="font-style:italic; text-decoration:none"><i>About the Poly Campus</i></span> |
<a href="devicelab.html">Open Device Lab</a> |
<a href="itprog.html">The Information Technology Major</a>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qh98f3k2/

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To italicise text, you can add `<i> </i>` tags around it, like

```
<i>Hello</i>
```

which will show up as *Hello*.

Alternative you can add `font-style:italic;` as css (recommended) or as inline-style like

```
style="font-style:italic;"
```

To make a link go nowhere, simply use a hashtag `#` where you would usually put the pagename, e.g.

```html
 <a href = "#" style="font-style:italic; text-decoration:none;">MyPage</a>
```

Adding `text-decoration:none;` gets rid of the default link underline

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```css
nav p{
  display:inline;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <p>Link 2</p>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this before but it puts it on 3 separate lines when it is supposed to be on the same line.

Comment: did you use....`display: inline` css property?..... by default `p` is block level element, so it will consume the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to style the link with href="#"